# Why does the condition for a breakpoint failed to execute?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, conditional-breakpoint

I want to temporarily disable a breakpoint for a short time, so I set a conditional breakpoint with the following condition:

```
(global::System.DateTime.Now<new global::System.DateTime(2014,03,28,11,0,0))
```

When this breakpoint is hit a dialog pops up, saying

```
The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute. The condition was 
'(global::System.DateTime.Now<new
global::System.DateTime(2014,03,28,11,0,0))'. The error returned was
'The runtime has refused to evaluate the expression at this time.'. Click
OK to stop at this breakpoint.
```

Why has the runtime refused to evaluate the expression?

What can I do to get the desired behavior without modifying the debugged source code?

Comment: what is your desired behaviour ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843683/vs2013-debugger-entity-framework-runtime-has-refused-to-evaluate-the-express

Comment: @Tigran disable a breakpoint for an adjustable time (e.g. over lunch)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From VS2012 on, you have to switch to the Managed Compatibility Mode, to use conditional breakpoints. Why (sorry, no more why from MS since that link is broken.. I added link to archive.org) and how is described here:

[switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/)

[old Microsoft link, now dead](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

[the original Microsoft article on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150311000321/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Comment: It's odd that they don't even mention conditional breakpoints as one of the reasons to switch to the older mode!

Comment: Yes, it works after switching to the compatibility mode.

Comment: Dead link, [this seems to work](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/).

Comment: I added the broken article back from archive.org

Answer (score -2):

It's not possible as far as I know.  What you *can* do instead is use of [HitCount](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/28/breakpoint-hit-count-vstipdebug0019.aspx)

or hardcode with a timer (as you like) in `C#` code

```
#if DEBUG 
  if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
     System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

Comment: hard coding is not an option as you cannot change the behavior during a debug session, hit count would require statistical data upfront to have any timely meaning

Comment: @mbx: what behaviour are you talking about ?

Comment: behaviour for a breakpoint - can change the condition at runtime during a debug session - just break, change the condition for the breakpoint and continue

Comment: @mbx: _HitCount_ is best what you can basically afaik, for this case.