# Visual Studio 2013 Conditional Breakpoint fails to evaluate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, conditional-breakpoint

Visual Studio 2013 conditional breakpoint fails to evaluate.

> The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute. .... Evaluation of native methods in this content is not supported.

Yet the Quick Watch will evaluate just fine.

Is there a way around this?
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709169/why-does-the-condition-for-a-breakpoint-failed-to-execute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033786/condition-for-a-breakpoint-failed-to-execute-variable-not-declared-it-may-b

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166874/unable-to-evaluate-expression-whilst-debugging

Comment: Nathan, your link to stackoverflow 21166874 seem to solve the problem.  If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks but that's not necessary. This type of issues could be easily solved by searching error message texts on stackoverflow though.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project in the solution explorer and select `Clean` command then rebuild the project with break point

Also make sure both project and solution is in debug mode